# How to comment once only in single line include two or more same keywords in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

when I click one keyword(which need to be commented) and use **Alt + F3** to select all lines included, then I use shortcut **CTRL+K CTRL+C** or **CTRL+/**, then I find the line with two or more same keywords will be commented twice or more. and this can be a problem to remove the comments .  Is it possible to solve the problem?

example, need to comment hello:

```
hello world hello world

hello
```

after comment:

```
-- -- hello world hello world

-- hello
```

Comment: I see this too.  In general, if you try to comment a line that has two or more cursors in it - you will get that many comment punctuations added.  `Is it a bug though?`  You can double comment a line if you wish - I occasionally do when it is part of a larger selection that gets commented.  Opinions?

Comment: In your case, you could hit `End` to put a single cursor at the end of each of your lines with your selected keyword in it and then comment the lines with Ctrl+/ or similar..

Comment: thank u, the workaround work well.